# Unable to get gitlab runners registration token from database

Tags: ansible, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-omnibus

I'm trying to completely deploy my gitlab cicd stack with ansible and automatically register runners.

I use the below task in my playbook to get registration token and store it in facts for my runners further registration, as I saw in several tutorial that we can get the registration token from gitlab database.

The ansible playbook task :

```
- name: Extract Runner Registration Token directly from Gitlab DB
    become: true
    become_user: gitlab-psql
    vars:
        ansible_ssh_pipelining: true
        query: "SELECT runners_registration_token FROM application_settings ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"
        psql_exec: "/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/psql"
        gitlab_db_name: "gitlabhq_production"
    shell: '{{ psql_exec }} -h /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/ -d {{ gitlab_db_name }} -t -A -c "{{ query }}"'
    register: gitlab_runner_registration_token_result
```

But this task doesn't get back any **registration token** (get an empty string) cause the **runners_registration_token** column does not exist in the **application_settings** table. However the `runners_registration_token_encrypted` column exists, but the `runners_registration_token_encrypted` string returned is rejected by `runner-register` api.

Thus I have to copy runners registration token from the gitlab gui (in **admin/runners**), hardcode it in the playbook and run the playbook again to succeed registration stack.

Can someone explain where gitlab stores its runners registration token displayed in the GUI (I noticed it's same after rebooting the gitlab server, it doesn't change)?
Is it definitively impossible to automate gitlab runners registration token retrieval for automatic runners non-interactive registration?
Do you guys have any idea about the right way to achieve this please?

Answer (score 6):

Maybe use the rails console on the application Server?
Put the following in a shell or command, run it on the gitlab application server and catch the output:

```
gitlab-rails runner -e production "puts Gitlab::CurrentSettings.current_application_settings.runners_registration_token"
```

So with Ansible something like this:

```
- name: Extract Runner Registration Token directly from Gitlab Rails console
    become: true
    shell: 'gitlab-rails runner -e production "puts Gitlab::CurrentSettings.current_application_settings.runners_registration_token"'
    register: gitlab_runner_registration_token_result
```

Answer (score 2):

This way using Ansible, I can obtain the Gitlab runner registration token from my private Gitlab server and use it on the runner host to register a docker runner automatically:

```
- name: obtain registration token
  when: gitlab_host is defined
  delegate_to: "{{ gitlab_host }}"
  command: 'gitlab-rails runner -e production "puts Gitlab::CurrentSettings.current_application_settings.runners_registration_token"'
  register: runners_registration_token
  changed_when: false

- name: set gitlab_runner_token
  when: gitlab_host is defined and runners_registration_token.rc == 0
  set_fact:
    gitlab_runner_token: "{{ runners_registration_token.stdout }}"

- name: register docker runner
  when: docker_runner|bool
  command: |
    gitlab-ci-multi-runner register \
    --non-interactive \
    --url "{{ gitlab_external_url }}" \
    --registration-token "{{ gitlab_runner_token|quote }}" \
    --description "docker-runner" \
    --executor "docker" \
    --docker-network-mode="host" \
    --docker-tlsverify=false \
    --docker-privileged \
    --tag-list '{{ gitlab_runner_tags | join(",") }}' \
    --docker-image='{{ gitlab_runner_image |default('alpine') }}'
```

Role is available [dockpack.gitlab_runner](https://github.com/dockpack/gitlab_runner.git)

Answer (score 0):

> Do you guys have any idea about the right way to achieve this please?

The correct way is via [their API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/runners.html#get-runners-details). It is very, very, very unwise to allow anyone -- ansible playbooks included -- to have access to the gitlab database.

Separately, while not especially relevant to your specific query, it is a very good habit to get into to using [`quote`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#id8) when feeding jinja variables into a shell string

Comment: Thx @Matthew for your answer, but it's not possible to retrieve a registration token via the API. The documentation ask you to get the token from the gitlab GUI and the use it to register runners.

Comment: Yes @Matthew, I second nixmind... you can't get this through API. There is a 2y old issue in GitLab Comunity Edition mentioning this - https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/24030

Comment: Point taken about quote filter, but note the command module, not using shell when command is sufficient is a best practice too.

Comment: Token is removed in version '13.0' see comment in your linked documentation.