# How to get Gitlab runner registration token from command line?

Tags: terraform, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to deploy a Gitlab instance and runners ready with Terraform. The script creates both Gitlab and runners without any problem, but I don't know how to register the runners automatically after the creation.

Is there any way to get the registration token from command line? If it's possible I can register just calling external data source using Terraform.

Answer (score 5):

The [projects API endpoint](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#get-single-project) response contains the `runners_token` key. You can use this to automatically fetch the runner tokens for any project.

You can then use that in a few ways. One way would be to have your runner registration script fetch the runner token itself such as with this example:

```sh
curl --fail --silent --header "Private-Token: ${GITLAB_API_TOKEN}" "https://$GITLAB_URL/api/v4/projects/${PROJECT}"
```

Or you could use the [Gitlab Terraform provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/gitlab)'s [`gitlab_project` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/gitlab/d/project.html) to fetch this from whatever is running Terraform and then inject it into the thing that runs the registration script such as a templated file:

```
data "gitlab_project" "example" {
  id = 30
}

locals {
  runner_config = {
    runner_token = data.gitlab_project.example.runners_token
  }
}

output "example" {
  value = templatefile("${path.module}/register-runners.sh.tpl", local.runner_config)
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this for a shared runner and not to be project-specific?

Comment: Not easily. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/16319 has some discussion about adding it to the API (or alternatively allowing registration via personal access tokens) as a feature request but not being worked on or prioritised. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54136551/2291321 explains how to get at the shared runners registration token programatically but it requires using the Rails console to read the value. It can also be found encrypted in the database but I don't know a good way to reverse that without having access to the application server so you may as well use the console.

Comment: Personally I put the shared runner registration token in our secret store (SSM Parameter Store in our case) and leave it at that. When I need to rotate the secret then I have to do this one by hand but the rotation is also triggered manually so isn't that bad.

Comment: Thanks -- wasn't clear to me, but can the same token be used to install multiple runner instances? I've believed a unique token was required for each instance -- is that not the case? I'm trying to automate the installation of 1 or more runners on a newly provisioned VM.

Comment: It's not unique no. It's just a randomly generated string for the instance/group/project and you can reset if it if the secret is compromised (if you have access to the secret and network access to Gitlab you can impersonate a runner and thus get access to source code) but is otherwise long lived.

Comment: Please see my answer below. Yes, it is possible to get the shared runner token.

Answer (score 4):

***Yes, you can.***

The command has to be run on the server hosting your Gitlab instance. The line below will output the current shared runner token.

```
sudo gitlab-rails runner -e production "puts Gitlab::CurrentSettings.current_application_settings.runners_registration_token"
```

As others have mentioned, there is not API endpoint that currently allows this (there has been discussion over this for quite some time [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/16319). However, I find this solution satisfactory for my needs.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted. It's worth noting though, the command will take quite a while, like 15-20 minutes before it completes.

Comment: That's surprising. I haven't had it take any more than a few seconds to return the shared runner token.

Comment: It takes ~35 seconds here, but any command that uses `gitlab-rails runner` or attempts to start a rails console takes 30-40 seconds, so I'm kind of used to it.

Answer (score 0):

Credits for this answer go to [MxNxPx](https://github.com/MxNxPx). [This script](https://github.com/MxNxPx/gitlab-cicd-demo/blob/aee86e45f5bc603a5055f0cd391cd6b184f1d6c3/get-runner-reg.sh) used to work (for me) two days ago:

```
GITUSER="root"
GITURL="http://127.0.0.1"
GITROOTPWD="mysupersecretgitlabrootuserpassword"

# 1. curl for the login page to get a session cookie and the sources with the auth tokens
body_header=$(curl -k -c gitlab-cookies.txt -i "${GITURL}/users/sign_in" -sS)

# grep the auth token for the user login for
#   not sure whether another token on the page will work, too - there are 3 of them
csrf_token=$(echo $body_header | perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /new_user.*?authenticity_token"[[:blank:]]value="(.+?)"/' | sed -n 1p)

# 2. send login credentials with curl, using cookies and token from previous request
curl -sS -k -b gitlab-cookies.txt -c gitlab-cookies.txt "${GITURL}/users/sign_in" \
    --data "user[login]=${GITUSER}&user[password]=${GITROOTPWD}" \
    --data-urlencode "authenticity_token=${csrf_token}"  -o /dev/null

# 3. send curl GET request to gitlab runners page to get registration token
body_header=$(curl -sS -k -H 'user-agent: curl' -b gitlab-cookies.txt "${GITURL}/admin/runners" -o gitlab-header.txt)
reg_token=$(cat gitlab-header.txt | perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /code id="registration_token">(.+?)</' | sed -n 1p)
echo $reg_token
```

However, as of today it stopped working. I noticed the second `body_header` variable is empty. Upon inspecting the `gitlab-header.txt` file, I noticed it contained:

> You are being [redirected](http://127.0.0.1/users/sign_in).

Whereas I would expect it to be signed in at that point, with a `gitlab-header.txt` file that contains the respective `runner registration token`. I expect I am doing something wrong, however, perhaps there has been an update to the `gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest` package such that a change to the script is required.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer, I am involved in creating that code
[Here](https://github.com/a-t-0/get-gitlab-runner-registration-token) is a *horrible* but working Python boiler plate code that gets the runner token and exports it to a parent repository: https://github.com/a-t-0/get-gitlab-runner-registration-token.

### Independent usage

It requires a few manual steps to set up, and then gets the GitLab runner registration token automatically (from the CLI with:). It requires Conda and Python however, and downloads a browser controller. So it is most likely wiser to look a bit better into the curl commands instead.

### Integrated in parent [bash] repository

First install the conda environment, then activate it. After that, you can execute the function below automatically from the CLI (if you put that function in a file at path `parent_repo/src/get_gitlab_server_runner_token.sh`, assuming you have the credentials etc as specified in the Readme), with:

```
cd parent_repo
source src/get_gitlab_server_runner_token.sh && get_registration_token_with_python
```

This bash function gets the token:

```
get_registration_token_with_python() {
    # delete the runner registration token file if it exist
    if [ -f "$RUNNER_REGISTRATION_TOKEN_FILEPATH" ] ; then
        rm "$RUNNER_REGISTRATION_TOKEN_FILEPATH"
    fi
    
    
    git clone https://github.com/a-t-0/get-gitlab-runner-registration-token.git &&
    set +e
    cd get-gitlab-runner-registration-token && python -m code.project1.src
    cd ..
}
```

And here is a BATS test that verifies the token is retrieved:

```
#!./test/libs/bats/bin/bats

load 'libs/bats-support/load'
load 'libs/bats-assert/load'
load 'libs/bats-file/load'

source src/get_gitlab_server_runner_token.sh
source src/hardcoded_variables.txt

@test "Checking if the gitlab runner registration token is obtained correctly." {
    
    get_registration_token_with_python
    actual_result=$(cat $RUNNER_REGISTRATION_TOKEN_FILEPATH)
    EXPECTED_OUTPUT="somecode"

    assert_file_exist $RUNNER_REGISTRATION_TOKEN_FILEPATH
    assert_equal ${#actual_result}   20
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set an environment with your token. Works only on a fresh setup of gitlab:

`GITLAB_SHARED_RUNNERS_REGISTRATION_TOKEN`

from:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/environment_variables.html

OR in the omnibus config:

`gitlab_rails['initial_shared_runners_registration_token'] = "token"`

from:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/-/blob/881cc7d2072ebdd496dc03f62a8bda82135acd37/files/gitlab-config-template/gitlab.rb.template#L714